# Evaluate $\int_{|z| = 4} {{e^z - e^{-z}}\over{z^4}}\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the easiest way to evaluate$$\int_{|z| = 4} {{e^z - e^{-z}}\over{z^4}}\,dz?$$Here, we're traversing the circle counterclockwise.

Comment: Use the power series for $e^z$ and $e^{-z}$.

Comment: nominator is $\sin(z)$ and is analytic. find the residue at $z=0$ which is the coefficient of the term $\frac{1}{z}$ in the  Laurent series expansion of integrand. solution : $\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
f(z)=\frac{\mathrm{e}^z-\mathrm{e}^{-z}}{z^4}=\sum_{k=-3}^\infty c_kz^k,
$$
where
$$
c_{-1}=\frac{1}{3}
$$
and hence
$$
\int_{\lvert z\rvert=4}f(z)\,dz=2\pi i c_{-1}=\ldots
$$

Comment: You have $\;c_{-1}=\frac16\;$ , I have $\;c_{-1}=\frac13\;$ . At least one of the two of us is wrong. I think it is you but, of course, perhaps it is me.

Comment: Indeed, it is $c_1=1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Power series (around zero, of course) as proposed by David Ullrich seems to be the shortest and easiest way to go:

$$\frac1{z^4}\left(e^z-e^{-z}\right)=\frac1{z^4}\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^3}6+\ldots-\left(1-z+\frac{z^2}2-\frac{z^3}6+\ldots\right)\right)=$$

$$\frac1{z^4}\left(2z+\frac{z^3}3+\ldots\right)=\frac1{z^3}+\frac1{3z}+\ldots$$